# Problem to extracte a address of HyperLink in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want display the address of Hyperlink. I find the code below.

```
Sub test()
    Dim hLink As Hyperlink
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet

    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
       For Each hLink In wSheet.Hyperlinks
            MsgBox hLink.Address
        Next hLink
    Next
End Sub
```

But I have de name Hyperlink as show the screenshot here :

[image]

Semeone can help me ?

Comment: So what should the `Address` be instead?  There's nothing wrong with your code...

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected for me:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim hLink As Hyperlink, ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each hLink In ws.Hyperlinks
            Debug.Print ws.Name, hLink.Range.Address, hLink.TextToDisplay, hLink.Address
        Next hLink
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: I have this result :
`Feuil1        $G$7          Scripts       Scripts`

Comment: That's telling me the `Address` property is actually "Scripts".  Not sure what you expect instead?  What happens when you click on that link?  Can you show a screenshot of the "Edit Hyperlink" window with the URL showing?

Comment: When I open the Hypertext link m y url is \\FMFRLAFILE02\Services\IT\***\***\Scripts.

Comment: I can't replicate that.  Can you share the workbook which shows that result?